# Creating conda environment using only symbolic links

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to create an environment which is an exact copy of my `root` environment, but not making any hard copies of packages (later I will add a few packages not in Anaconda). I thought I could do this with one of the following:

```
conda create -n newroot --clone root
conda create -n newroot --copy root
conda create -n newroot anaconda
```

But all of these download packages. How do I create an exact replica environment of the current Anaconda distribution? (I know later I can add packages with `conda install -n newroot <package name>`)

Comment: Could you show which packages it downloads? Conda is usually pretty good about making symlinks where possible. There is usually a solid design decision behind not doing so.

Answer (score 5):

`conda` uses hardlinks internally when it can (nearly always) so the cost of new environments is minimal, so my recommendation is to use:

```
conda create -n newroot --clone root
```

Do not use `--copy` since that explicitly avoids using hardlinks.