# Can conda environment inherit base packages?

Tags: python, conda

I'm looking for a solution where environments *do* inherit from root, but searching for the answer there seems to be a lot of confusion. Many OP questions believe they are inheriting packages when they are not. So, the search results find these questions, but the answer has the counter solution (or just explain they are mistaken).

That said, one OP actually has a similar objective. [Can packages be shared across Anaconda environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395044/can-packages-be-shared-across-anaconda-environments) This OP says they are running out of space on their HDD. The implication being "sharing" should use the same installed packages in the new environment. The answer (not accepted) is to use `--clone`.

I also found this post, [Do newly created conda envs inherit all packages from the base env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433517/do-newly-created-conda-envs-inherit-all-packages-from-the-base-env) which says `--clone` does not share packages. In this post the OP believed their new environment "shared" packages, and then concludes "shared" packages don't exist.
[What is the use of non-separated anaconda environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329107/what-is-the-use-of-non-separated-anaconda-environments/45863425#45863425)

I tested both the `--clone` flag, and the Conda Docs instructions to ["build identical environments"](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/master/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments) options. Both env directories have the same identical size: 2G+.

```
(base) $ conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
# Produced Size On Disk: 2.14 GB (2,305,961,984 bytes)

(base) conda create --name myclone --clone root
# Produced Size On Disk, clone: 2.14 GB (2,304,331,776 bytes)
```

The only difference was building identical environment downloaded the packages again, and clone coppied the local file taking *much less time*.

I use Miniconda to deploy CLI tools to coworker workstations. Basically, the tools all use the same packages, with the occasional exception, when I need to add a particular module which I don't want in the base install.

**The goal is to use conda create for environments that *extend* the base packages similar to `virtualenv --system-site-packages`, and not to duplicate their installation.**

---

## UPDATE 2020-02-08

Responding to @merv and his link to this post ([Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment)) which says Conda venvs inherit base packages by default. I had another opportunity this weekend with the problem. Here is the base case:

**Downloaded the [Miniconda installer](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Installed with settings**

- Install for me
- Install location: (C:\Users\xtian\Miniconda3_64) 
  NOTE: I added the `_64`
- Advanced Options

  - Add Anaconda to the system PATH variable, False
  - Register Anaconda as the system Python 3.7, True

**I updated pip and setuptools,**

> conda update pip setuptools

**Below, I list packages in `base`:**

```
(base) C:\Users\xtian>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\xtian\Miniconda3_64:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0
cffi                      1.13.2           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
conda                     4.8.2                    py37_0
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h62dcd97_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
cryptography              2.8              py37h7a1dbc1_0
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_0
openssl                   1.1.1d               he774522_3
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         2
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37he774522_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
pywin32                   227              py37he774522_1
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37he774522_0
setuptools                45.1.0                   py37_0
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.31.1               he774522_0
tqdm                      4.42.0                     py_0
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
```

**Then I successfully create new venv:**

```
(base) C:\Users\xtian>conda create -n wsgiserver
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\xtian\Miniconda3_64\envs\wsgiserver

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

**Here I activate the new wsgiserver virtual environment, list packages, and finally test with `pip`--but there is no `pip`! I tested today with 64 and 32 bit installers:**

```
(base) C:\Users\xtian>conda activate wsgiserver

(wsgiserver) C:\Users\xtian>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\xtian\Miniconda3_64\envs\wsgiserver:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

(wsgiserver) C:\Users\xtian>pip
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: So, what is your goal? Do you want to offer a locally hosted package cache, so that multiple installs are made faster (and no need to re-download when cloning)?

Comment: What I don't want to do is anger the IT-gods with Python CLI installations of multiples of 2G. (>_<)

Comment: Could you describe a scenario, that would solve your problem? Like: Install a global numpy in root and use that in every anaconda environment without re-installing?

Comment: I thought, that conda tries to hardlink wherever possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000773/creating-conda-environment-using-only-symbolic-links

Comment: A successful scenario would be to get everyone in the office on Linux and use virtualenv, but that's not going to happen. Regarding hard links, I think that assertion needs to be proven, because just creating the environment I can't run my base packages. Creating with the above methods create nearly identical size environments--_hence the confusion_.

Comment: So, what you are saying is, you want to have n environments with the same set of 2 GB of packages plus a different subset of packages on different envs. The "shared" packages should only be installed once and somehow linked to be used by each environment? I want that too!

Comment: I tried to reproduce and do some measurements. On Windows I cloned an existing environment, and ended up with a folder the exact same size as the "parent". I did a fresh Anaconda3 install on Ubuntu and cloned the "root" environment (aka base) and ended up with an environment folder roughly 230 MB, whereas the "lib" folder of the base image is already > 1GB. So, there's definitely some degree of linking going on.

Comment: _" I want that too! "_, And you can have it on Linux with virtualenv's; _"definitely some degree of linking going on"_  I dunno. `Anaconda3/Lib` is only 700MB on my system. While on the other hand, `Anaconda3/pkgs` is 2.58G--Not a lot of difference from 2.14G.  (BTW, the whole directory is 4G).

Comment: I cleaned the package cache before measurements using `conda clean -a`.

Comment: @xtian I am looking for exactly the same. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I’ve not found a solution to this problem, other than to not do project development in Anaconda the others describe. I have no more than two envs at a time: development and production. Production is the full current ecosystem of scripts and dev is future production—maybe.

Comment: Have you seen [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment)? How did you compute disk usage? If you counted each individually, then you are likely overestimating the real disk usage because of the hardlinking.

Comment: @merv, No. I hadn't. And today, needing to pip install in a conda environment, I found reference on Anaconda.org suggesting this is indeed the case: [_" In conda environments, hard links are used when possible rather than copying files to save space. If a similar set of packages are installed, each new conda environment will require only a small amount of additional disk space."_](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) (2018-12-04). I tested the measurement methods in your link using WSL to the same results. If you want to write these links up, I'll give you the answer.

Comment: @merv or post owner, could you write an answer and accept it, it seems helpful for me but someone might come and overlook the comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment)

Answer (score 16):

### *Should* Conda environments inherit base packages?

**No.** The recommended workflow is to use `conda create --clone` to create a new standalone environment, and then mutate that environment to add additional packages. Alternatively, one can dump the template environment to a YAML (`conda env export > env.yaml`), edit it to include or remove packages, and then create a new environment from that (`conda env create -f env.yaml -n foo`).

Concern about this wasting storage is unfounded in most situations.<sup>**1**</sup> There can be a mirage of new environments taking up more space than they really do, due to Conda's use of hardlinks to minimize redundancy. A more detailed analysis of this can be found in the question, [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment).

### Can Conda environments inherit base packages?

**It's not supported, but it's possible.** First, let's explicitly state that [nested activation of Conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation) via the `conda activate --stack` command does not enable or help to allow inheritance of Python packages across environments. This is because it does not manipulate `PYTHONPATH`, but instead only keeps the previous active environment on `PATH` and skips the deactivate scripts. A more detailed discussion of this is available in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9597).

Now that we've avoided that red herring, let's talk about `PYTHONPATH`. One can use this environment variable to include additional `site-packages` directories to search. So, naively, something like

```
conda activate foo
PYTHONPATH=$CONDA_ROOT/lib/python3.7/site-packages python
```

should launch Python with the packages of both **base** and **foo** available to it. A key constraint for this to work is that the Python in the new environment must match that of **base** up to and including the minor version (in this case 3.7.*).

#### Thinking through the details

While this will achieve package inheritance, we need to consider: *Will this actually conserve space?* I'd argue that *in practice* it likely won't, and here's why.

Presumably, we don't want to physically duplicate the Python installation, but the new environment must have a Python installed in order to help constrain solving for the new packages we want. To do this, we should not only match the Python version (`conda create -n foo python=3.7`), but rather the exact same build as **base**:

```
# first check base's python
conda list -n base '^python$'
# EXAMPLE RESULT
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
python                    3.7.6                h359304d_2 

# use this when creating the environment
conda create -n foo python=3.7.6=h359304d_2
```

This will let Conda do its linking thing and use the same physical copy in both environments. However, there is no guarantee that Python's dependencies will also reuse the packages in **base**. In fact, if any compatible newer versions are available, it will download and install those.

Furthermore, let's say that we now install `scikit-learn`:

```
conda install -n foo scikit-learn
```

This again is going to check for the newest versions of it and its dependencies, independent of whether older but compatible versions of those dependencies are already available through **base**. So, more packages are unnecessarily being installed into the package cache.

The pattern here seems to be that we really want to find a way to have the **foo** env install new packages, but use as many of the existing packages to satisfy dependencies. And that is exactly what `conda create --clone` already does.<sup>**2**</sup>

Hence, I lose the motivation to bother with inheritance altogether.

---

#### Note

I'd speculate that for the special case of pure Python packages it may be plausible to use [`pip install --target`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t) from the **base** environment to install packages compatible with **base** to a location outside of **base**. The user could then add this directory to `PYTHONPATH` before launching `python` from **base**.

This would not be my first choice. I know the clone strategy is manageable; I wouldn't know what to expect with this going long-term.

---

<sub>**[1]** This will hold as long as the locations of the package cache (`pkgs_dirs`) and where the environment is created (which defaults to `envs_dirs`) are on the same volume. Configurations with multiple volumes [should be using softlinks](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#disallow-soft-linking-allow-softlinks), which will ultimately have the same effect. Unless one has manually disabled linking of both types, Conda will do a decent job at silently minimizing redundancy.</sub>

<sub>**[2]** Technically, one might also have a stab at using the `--offline` flag to force Conda to use what it already has cached. However, the premise of OP is that the additional package is new, so it may not be wise to assume we already have a compatible version in the cache.</sub>

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: Re [1], another big exception is if the environment is created by another user. That is if anaconda is installed as root, and I `conda create --clone base --name myenv`, I get a full copy of base, not hardlinks. It looks like you can configure a [shared package cache](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/shared-pkg-cache/) but it must be writable by everyone.

Comment: And lots of folks seem to [have issues](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7227) with the shared package cache.

Comment: Huh, and if I do `conda create --clone base --name mybase` then `conda create --clone mybase --name myenv`, myenv is also a completely separate copy with no hardlinks. :(