# Libraries installed through conda in a virtual environment

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I am new to this but does conda, again and again, install the same libraries (let's say the versions are the same) for different virtual environments? Does it take the same amount of space each time for all the environments? If so, wouldn't it be too costly instead of installing that library globally on your system?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222405/can-conda-environment-inherit-base-packages